# How to remove margin from first page using Jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, margins

I am creating PDF report using JasperReport(jrxml). I am new in JasperReport so I have no idea for how to remove margin from first page.

My requirements is for in PDF report, first page is for cover page where I am showing company logo and company details and after cover page I am showing all required data.

please see my jrxml code, I am not showing all code just showing where I am using margin code

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="rpt_survey_analysis" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="df013db5-f76e-44d3-b0df-bcbc46d93160">
</jasperReport>
```

in this code, I set topMargin, bottomMargin, leftMargin, rightMargin but this margin is affected to all page. But i want to affect this margin except cover page. So how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 0 margin on your report, you can **not** have different margins for different bands

From [Understanding Bands](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/understanding-bands)

> A band is as wide as the page width (right and left margins excluded).

Once you have zero margin, a few solution could be:

1. **Position your elements** in other bands to create a "fake" margin example `x="20"`
2. Use a **frame component** with x position at margin and add your other components to this. example

   ```
   <frame>
       <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="550" height="40" uuid="0d4ab012-9161-4f37-b8e0-c6ddcdd3d550"/>
       <staticText>
           <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="30" uuid="3dc51fb0-0bc3-46f6-9259-fb8d9fd1f884"/>
           <text><![CDATA[Text at position 0 in a frame]]></text>
       </staticText>
   </frame>
   ```
3. Use a **subreport with margin**.

**main.jrxml**, no margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="NoMargins" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isTitleNewPage="true" uuid="4e2c1a7a-cbfd-4d60-9fe7-61aea15cc321">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="51" backcolor="#0015FF" uuid="e6616fe4-fed9-44aa-a8a6-2c296c6ab508">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="53" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="50" uuid="b654e952-f1e1-4b90-a4ca-2cf3abe9f6f4"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["with margins.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**sub report**, with margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="with margins" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="cccf2b18-4f7c-464c-bd9c-13dbb62af3b0">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="66542837-c420-4e7c-a760-dd55ccff2d17">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[My report with margin]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

I would probably prefer solution 1 or 2 in a simple report, in more complex reports in can be an advantage to have first in separate report

Comment: is it possbile without sub reports?

Comment: @AkashChavda Check solution 1: if you just set x="20" you are creating a margin, hence with no subreports. If you like to have x="0" in same report that is not possibile, different bands can not have different margins in same report

Comment: You can also insert frame components into report to create the margin, hence add a frame add x="20" then add your textField in frame with position x="0"

Comment: @AkashChavda I added example to show how it's done with frame

Comment: yes its solution for leftMargin but what about other and this trick not working for pageFooter. There is no any proper way like if we put if condition and check if current page is 1 then margion = 0 else margin = 20?

Comment: @AkashChavda no, the trick always work you need to use x="20" where you like 20 margin.